# Unable to pull WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 image from docker

Tags: docker, wso2-api-manager

We are trying to do a container based setup of APIM 4.0.0 on Openshift and for that trying to pull the image of the latest version of WSO2 APIM from docker using a valid subscription but not able to pull and getting the below error. Can someone please suggest how this issue can be fixed?

```
[admcoe@blrocpimpbastion ~]$ sudo docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes:latest
Trying to pull repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes ...
Pulling repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
[admcoe@blrocpimpbastion ~]$ sudo docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes ...
Pulling repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am-kubernetes
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Thanks,

Suman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following.

- Login to docker.wso2.com

> docker login docker.wso2.com

- Pull the latest docker image of APIM v4.

> docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am:4.0.0.0

Comment: Hi, getting the same error even with wso2am:4.0.0.0 .                                                        sudo docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am4.0.0.0
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am4.0.0.0 ...
Pulling repository docker.wso2.com/wso2am4.0.0.0
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Comment: Did you login to the docker registry first?

Comment: The correct image should be `docker.wso2.com/wso2am:4.0.0.0`. There should be a `:` before the image tag.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes we were able to pull the image. A : was missing.